# adding image in footer in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am new to Drupal.I am using marinelli theam.I created one block and placed in footer section with some text.In Drupal 7 how to add an image in a block located in footer section..I tried using Full HTML and filtered HTML Text format.It was not added image.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the path to the image is correct.

1- Enable "PHP Filter" module, in Drupal Core modules.

2- inside the block content, make sure that the text format is "PHP code" and then type the following code:

```
global $base_path;
print "<img alth='' src='" . $base_path . "PATH_TO_IMAGE/image.jpg' />";
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use a wysiwyg editor and use insert picture any where you want. I prefer CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is go to edit mode of your block. Then add image link using the following formatt:

```
    <a href="[the link address]"><img src="../sites/all/themes/marinelli /images/[your imagename and extension]"></a>
```

If you haven't got through, I hope this helps.